# Git: making a commit without changing file revision

Tags: git

Is there a way to make a commit with custom message, but without changing any file under revision control?

So the desired effect is:

1. Git log lists the commit, and the custom message
2. The commit does not change any file under revision control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is trivial: with no changes to commit, use `git commit --allow-empty`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a branch if you don't want to change the file.